# mongodb index query

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection which I query based on fields _id and CreationTimestamp.O as below:

```
var _query = Query.And(
 Query.EQ("_id", "TheId"),
    Query.GT("CreationTimestamp.0", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15).UtcTicks));
```

Should I create a compound index on both these fields? 
I know _id by default has an index.

I am looking for guidance on best practice i.e. Create a compound index for both fields or just create an index for CreationTimestamp.O as their is already an index on _id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much benefit in creating compound index here. Since the selectivity of autocreated index on `_id` field is 1 (it's unique index) there's no reason in having any compound index prefixed with it. The only possible benefit may be the fact MongoDB can use [covered index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes) for this query and possibly speedup the things (you need to benchmark on your data to prove this).